# Fastest way to create a trie (JSON) from a 4GB file, using only 1GB of ram?

Tags: java, node.js

Perhaps I'm doing this the wrong way:

I have a 4GB (33million lines of text) file, where each line has a string in it.

I'm trying to create a trie -> The algorithm works.
The problem is that Node.js has a process memory limit of 1.4GB, so the moment I process 5.5 million lines, it crashes.

To get around this, I tried the following:

Instead of 1 Trie, I create many Tries, each having a range of the alphabet.
For example:
aTrie ---> all words starting with a
bTrie ---> all words starting with b...
etc...

But the problem is, I still can't keep all the objects in memory while reading the file, so each time I read a line, I load / unload a trie from disk. When there is a change I delete the old file, and write the updated trie from memory to disk.

This is SUPER SLOW! Even on my macbook pro with SSD.

I've considered writing this in Java, but then the problem of converting JAVA objects to json comes up (same problem with using C++ etc).

Any suggestions ?

Comment: FIY, you can easily convert java object to json with gson : http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Would it be possible to stick the trie in an in-memory database instead of files/RAM?

Comment: @kuporific I don't understand - won't there be the same problem ? Can you explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may extend memory size limit that the node process uses by specifying the option below;

ps: size in mb's.

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096
```

for more options please see:
https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-flags/blob/master/flags-0.11.md

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 26 Tries you could use a hash function to create an arbitrary number of sub-Tries. This way, the amount of data you have to read from disk is limited to the size of your sub-Trie that you determine. In addition, you could cache the recently used sub-Tries in memory and then persist the changes to disk asynchronously in the background if IO is still a problem.

Comment: that sounds really complicated to synchronise, and ultimately use. Can you explain ?

Comment: That might be overkill - how much memory does your MacBook have?

Comment: my macbook has 16GB. But node.js has a limit of 1.4GB

Comment: You could build your data structure in Redis and run it separately - I think it should be able to comfortably handle that much data. It is pretty much a key-value store so you should be able to represent nodes as records easily.